# Css - Using pictures for pseudo-elements

Tags: css

I found [This](http://pepsized.com/icon-fonts-in-use-with-a-fancy-hover-effect/) article but I want to use a picture in ::before and ::after content attribute, not Font Icons.

Original:

```
.icon-dribbble:before, .icon-dribbble:after {
  content: "\e007";
}
```

The best I've come up so far (Which doesn't work, The pic does show up but It doesn't work as intended like in the article):

```
.icon-dribbble:before, .icon-dribbble:after {
  background-image: url('icon.png');
  background-repeat:space;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  background-position:center;
  top:0px;
  content: "";
   }
```

Comment: Add `display: block; height: 40px; width: 40px` to it ??

Comment: What does "doesn't work as intended" mean? Also, `background-repeat:space;` is not a valid value for `background-repeat` AFAIK.

Comment: can you create a demo?

Comment: @LinkinTED Doesn't work :( Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/fzxqmbzr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your pseudo elements, with no content in them, have nothing to size themselves to so you'll need to size them manually. Firstly, set their `display` value to `block` or `inline-block`, whichever suits your needs. Then set the `height` and `width` to the size of your image, which I'm guessing is 40 pixels square.

Also, you've set a value for the `top` property, without setting one for `position`. I've assumed and used `absolute` below.

**NOTE:** While the above points still apply, the below has been heavily edited from the orginal solution provided following many clarifications from the asker.

```css
.icon{
  background:#404040;
  border-radius:50%;
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:60px;
  position:relative;
  text-indent:60px;
  transition:background .5s;
  white-space:norwap;
  width:60px;
}
.icon:hover{
  background:#3c9;
}
.icon::before,.icon::after{
  background-position:center center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:40px 40px;
  content:"";
  display:block;
  height:40px;
  left:10px;
  position:absolute;
  transition:top .5s;
  width:40px;
}
.icon::before{
  background-image:url('http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/images/resize3.png');
  top:10px;
}
.icon::after{
  /* You'll need a different image below */
  background-image:url('http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/images/resize3.png');
  top:70px;
}
.icon:hover::before{
  top:-70px;
}
.icon:hover::after{
  top:10px;
}
.icon:hover::before{
  top:-70px;
}
```

```html
<a class="icon" href="#">text</a>
```

Comment: Tried your code but it didn't work, Here is a JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/fzxqmbzr/

Comment: Looks perfectly OK to me. What are you expecting it to look like?

Comment: I mean, a second picture should also appear from the bottom when you hover over the element.

Comment: Ah, OK, that wasn't clear. You need to change the `top` value for the `::after` pseudo element to have it appear outside its parent and then adjust the `top` values of both pseudo elements using a transition on `:hover`. You'll also need a second version of your image with the colour change.

Comment: Updated my answer to demonstrate. Incidentally, there are plenty of font icons out there with the cog icon you're looking for, such as FontAwesome.

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts. I was trying to change top and height values just as you told but I couldn't get it working. Thx god u posted the answer. Its my first time with pseudo-elements to be honest so I was struggling for few days lol. I will read your code many times to understand it. Thx again.

Comment: Sorry to re-comment again, but there is a small issue with the pictures transition. When you hover over the button, You will see some white pixels appear around the picture (FireFox Only). Is it possible to prevent that?

Comment: That's down to your images, nothing to do with this code. If you're using 8-bit PNGs, they won't have an alpha channel. Try using 24-bit PNGs instead. While you're at it, resize them to the size you actually need them to be to save yourself a few bytes of data then use tinypng.com to optimise them further.